# Unable to pass amount in paypal using _xclick

Tags: php, html, paypal, shopping-cart

I am trying to create simple PayPal button who pass amount and quantity details to PayPal. I am unable to pass hardcore amount in PayPal. I am expecting to show result like this:
[Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QCmV.jpg)

Problem is that my amount is not transferring to PayPal. Please support to resolve. Here is my code:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" amount="1.0">
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="hmmdmlk@gmail.com">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="Item #1">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="1.00">

<input type="submit" value="PayPal">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

When using _xclick, which is for operations on a single item, you want:

```
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="The item name.">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="1.00">
```

The multi-item parameters you were using would be for _cart with upload=1, not _xclick

Documentation: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx-websitestandard-htmlvariables/